# Can't write to Firebase Real Time Database

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

So, i've setup up a project on Firebase and followed many tutorials on how to connect firebase to my flutter application. I started by reading FlutterFire docs, step by step, and i managed to install the **FlutterFire CLI**. After that, i went straight into reading the **Realtime Database** section and whenever i try to write into the db, nothing happens.

The database is in test mode, firebase is correctly initialised inside the project and i get no errors while trying to write inside it, so i think that even the URL is correct (but i might be wrong)

Here's the code i used:

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart'; //generated with FlutterFire CLI
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: Platform.isWindows ? null : DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform, //not working on windows
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("/");

  

  void writeToFirebase() async {
    print('wrote to database');

    await ref.set({
      'title': 'Hello World',
      'body': 'This is my first post',
      'userId': '123',
    });

   await ref.child('title').set('Hello World');
    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: writeToFirebase,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }
}
```

I noticed that when the `print()` statement is above  `ref.set()` , i see the output in the console. But, if i put it beneath the  `ref.set()`  statement, i see no output. So, this makes me think that the  `ref.set()` does never end its execution or something like that.

I'm 2 weeks in learning flutter and i really can't make Firebase work

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `await`, did you consider using `try`-`catch` too so that you can catch and log any errors?

So:

```
void writeToFirebase() async {
  print('Start writing to database');
  try {
    await ref.set({
      'title': 'Hello World',
      'body': 'This is my first post',
      'userId': '123',
    });

    await ref.child('title').set('Hello World');
  }
  catch (error) {
    print(error);
  }
  finally {
    print('Done writing to database');
  }
}
```

Comment: It prints 'Start writing to database' and doesn't go further. Did i miss something that might be useful for solving the issue?

Comment: That typically means the write is either not being sent, or the server never responds back. Are you sure your `firebase_options` contains the correct database URL, and that you actually have a connection to the database.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what i should be looking for inside ```firebase_options```?
Also, how do i actually verify that the db connection is alright? I'm not that sure at this point that the connection is established.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on it. And everything was fine. The code was all good but it wasn't allowing me to insert data into realtime database, also it wasn't showing any error or log then I try this and it worked.
You can use this. Give your realtime database url in place of datase_url and it will work

```
FirebaseDatabase _database = FirebaseDatabase(app: null,databaseURL: "database_url");

final databaseReference = _database.reference();
if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
  print("here");
  await databaseReference
      .child('online-status')
      .child(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .set({"ok" : false});
}
```